# How to SELECT a sibling in an adjacency list type table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the next sibling in a list according to an integer `position` column. Rows are siblings when they have the same `parent_id`.

Given that sibling *foo.id = 192* and *foo.position = 0*, I want to get sibling *bar* that has a position of *foo.position + 1*

The below query returns the right result except that the `AND a.position = 0+1` should not be hardcoded.

```
SELECT a.title as taskTitle, b.title as projectTitle
FROM tasks a 
INNER JOIN tasks b
ON a.parent_id = (
    SELECT parent_id FROM tasks WHERE id = 192
)
AND a.position = 0+1
AND a.root_id = b.id;
```

The following query won't work of course but shows what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT a.title as taskTitle, b.title as projectTitle
FROM tasks a 
INNER JOIN tasks b
ON a.parent_id = (
    SELECT parent_id, position as pos FROM tasks WHERE id = 192
)
AND a.position = pos+1
AND a.root_id = b.id;
```

Is this possible without first querying the needed information and saving it into a variable to use in a second query?

Would it be faster than saving the result of a "pre-query" to use in a second query?

### EDIT:

Here's some test queries that set up a demo

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    root_id int unsigned,               /* top level task */
    parent_id int unsigned,             /* the task id that is the parent of this task */
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    position int unsigned,              /* the index in the array that will contain this task */
    FOREIGN KEY (root_id) REFERENCES tasks(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tasks(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO tasks (root_id, parent_id, `title`, position) VALUES 
(NULL, NULL, 'Foo Project', 0),
(NULL, NULL, 'Bar Project', 1),
(NULL, NULL, 'Baz Project', 2);

INSERT INTO tasks (root_id, parent_id, `title`, position) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Foo Child A', 0),
(1, 1, 'Foo Child B', 1),
(2, 2, 'Bar Child A', 0);

INSERT INTO tasks (root_id, parent_id, `title`, position) VALUES 
(2, 6, 'Bar Child A Grandchild 1', 0),
(1, 5, 'Foo Child B Grandchild 1', 0),
(1, 5, 'Foo Child B Grandchild 2', 1);
```

#### Query for needed info

The following query is suboptimal but retrieves the info needed.

```
SELECT a.title as taskTitle, b.title as projectTitle
FROM tasks a 
INNER JOIN tasks b
ON a.parent_id = (
    SELECT parent_id FROM tasks WHERE id = 8
)
AND a.position = (SELECT position FROM tasks WHERE id = 8)+1
AND a.root_id = b.id;
```

Comment: *Given that sibling foo.id = 192 and foo.position = 0, I want to get sibling bar that has a position of foo.position + 1* Does you have a guarantee that `foo.position + 1` value is present in the table (i.e. no holes in this field values)?

Comment: No, it can be null or an empty result set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need

```
SELECT t1.title taskTitle, 
       t2.title projectTitle
FROM tasks t1
JOIN tasks t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id
             AND t1.position + 1 = t2.position
WHERE t1.id = 192
```

Comment: This doesn't quite return the result that my query returns. Your query returns both sibling tasks, where the `taskTitle` column holds the title of sibling at position 0 and `projectTitle` holds sibling at position 1. What I need is the sibling at position 1 to be in the `taskTitle` column and the title of the siblings' root task, noted by `root_id` in my query, to be in the `projectTitle` column.

Comment: @slanden Does you want to say it is enough to swap output fields names?

Comment: Swapping `taskTitle` and `projectTitle` won't do because even after the swap, the result put into `projectTitle` is not right. It's just a direct sibling in the nested structure of tasks and I need the root task's title.

Comment: @slanden It seems I cannot understand the whole algo you need to realize. Maybe you can to add a small sample data (5-6 records) and the result for it?

Comment: I edited the post with some queries.